# Как подключить библиотеку nlohmann/json?

Tags: c++, github, cmake

Пытаюсь разобраться с подключением одной библиотеки с GitHub, в корне проекта лежит файл CMakeLists.txt, но его сборка не дает файлов библиотеки для линковки. Обратился к инструкции - оказалось, что нужно подключать папку для сборки, но этой папки я не нашел в корне проекта. Подскажите пожалуйста, как подключать такие библиотеки к проекту, был только опыт сборки статических библиотек с помощью cmake

[Библиотека с GitHub](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) и 
[Инструкция для CMake](https://github.com/nlohmann/json/blob/develop/README.md#cmake)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по readme, библиотека - header-only.

То есть компилировать ее не нужно, достаточно скачать и подключить заголовочный файл: `single_include/nlohmann/json.hpp`.

Comment: Как тогда подключить саму библиотеку к существующему проекту cmake?

Comment: Кажется я понял. Весь исходных код в заголовочных файлах? Зачем тогда проекту нужна система сборки?

Comment: @sddvxd Я так понимаю, если проект использует cmake, то можно для удобства подключать библиотеку через ее CMakeLists.txt (`find_package(nlohmann_json ...)` и т.п.). Судя по readme, это дает только автоматическое указание пути к заголовочному файлу и включение флажка для поддержки C++11. А можно этого не делать и просто заинклудить хедер.

Comment: Ну инклюдить хедер всё равно придётся.